# How to pass ctypes.POINTER to boost.python

Tags: python, c++, boost, ctypes, boost-python

I have following code:

old_lib.h:

```
struct DUMMY
{
    // some members
};
```

module.cpp:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include "old_lib.h"

namespace py = boost::python;

void foo(py::object const& p)
{
    // How to get rid of ctypes.addressof()?
    static py::object ctypes_addressof = py::import("ctypes").attr("addressof");
    DUMMY *ptr = *reinterpret_cast<DUMMY**>(uintptr_t(py::extract<uintptr_t>(ctypes_addressof(p))));
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(module)
{
    py::def("foo", &foo, args("p"));
}
```

old_python.py:

```
import ctypes
class DUMMY(ctypes.Structure):
    _pack_ = 4
PDUMMY = POINTER(DUMMY)
# some old stuff using PDUMMY
```

new_python.py:

```
from module import foo
from old_python import PDUMMY
x = PDUMMY()
# some calls to old python (e.g. initialization of x)
foo(x)
```

It's supposed that python code is unchangeable.

**How to get rid of ctypes.addressof()?** I guess, calling of it is more expensive than just extracting of value, especially in case of frequent calls of foo().
**UPD: In other words, how to obtain a value of ctypes._Pointer instance without using ctypes.addressof()?**

Is there a way to specify a type of argument as 'foo(PDUMMY p)' and write converter from ctypes.POINTER to PDUMMY?

Comment: `ctypes.POINTER` is a factory function, not a type. The class is `ctypes._Pointer`, but generally you shouldn't directly subclass it because ctypes caches pointer types for the sake of type checking.

Comment: @eryksun: It's necessary to have foo() as C++ function. I intentionally simplified the example for describing the issue of argument passing. In my project there is object's constructor instead of foo().

Comment: @eryksun: It's a plain C struct. I don't even know its members because it matters to "old" code only.

Comment: @eryksun: No, I shouldn't. It's sufficient to have just a pointer. However, that is not the subject of the topic. The main problem is how to get rid of ctypes.addressof(). In other words, how to obtain value of ctypes._Pointer instance without using ctypes.addressof()?

Comment: @eryksun: You missed the line of comment: `# some calls to old python (e.g. initialization of x).`

Comment: You could just pass the pointer as a Python integer. The most efficient way to get that is `p = ctypes.c_void_p.from_buffer(x).value`. Still, whether in Python or C++ or whether calling `addressof` and dereferencing or the `from_buffer` method, there's no legitimate way around calling a ctypes function to get at the internal [`b_ptr` field](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/b4cbecbc0781/Modules/_ctypes/ctypes.h#l46) of the object. I suppose you could be evil enough to use `b_ptr` directly...

Comment: @eryksun: Thanks a lot. `ctypes.c_void_p.value` suits perfectly. I can change definition of PDUMMY to `PDUMMY = ctypes.c_void_p`.