# Passing glm.mat4 from Python back to C++ (glm::mat4)

Tags: python, c++, boost

I have a boost python application that exports a class to Python, performs a calculation and returns the output back to C++:

```
import engine # c++ library
import glm # pyglm

class Game(engine.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        engine.Application.__init__(self, title, fullscreen)
        self.shader = engine.Shader();
        self.shader.setup("shader.vs", "shader.fs")
        self.shader.setMat4("model", glm.mat4(1.0)
    def update(self):
        ...
```

Amongst other classes, the shader is being wrapped and exported from C++ like this:

```
struct ShaderWrap : Shader, boost::python::wrapper<Shader>
{
  int setup(const char* vertexPath, const char* fragmentPath)
  {
    return Shader::setup(vertexPath, fragmentPath);
  }
  int setMat4(std::string name, glm::mat4 mat)
  {
    return Shader::setMat4(name, mat);
  }
};

...

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(engine)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;

  ...

  python::class_<ShaderWrap, boost::noncopyable>("Shader")
    .def("setup", &Shader::setup)
    .def("setMat4", &Shader::setMat4)
    ;

  ...
}
```

The application works fine up until the `self.shader.setMat4` call and I get the error:

```
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    StaticShader.setMat4(StaticShader, str, glm::detail::tmat4x4)
did not match C++ signature:
    setMat4(StaticShader {lvalue}, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, glm::mat<4, 4, float, (glm::qualifier)0>)
```

I've tried to pass the mat4 value as a float* back to C++ with no success.
I've also tried calling `value_ptr(mat4)` which returns a `c_void_p`, but the compiler complains saying `c_void_p` and `void*` are not the same type (also tried various attempts of casting it with the `ctypes` library).
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30220223/how-to-pass-ctypes-pointer-to-boost-python) question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30591085/boost-python-converter-for-pointers-doesnt-work) question are the basically the same problem but I got lost in the implementation.

In the PyGLM documentation, the developer says the library is written in C++. So,

**What would be a possible way to pass through a `glm.mat4` value to C++ to be interpreted as a `glm::mat4` value?**

I want to pass a glm.mat4 such as the view matrix, being updated in the Python code update function back to C++ to be further used, and was hoping there would be a fairly simple interface between the pyGLM library/GLM library through boost::python. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up contacting the developer about this issue and this was there response:

This is what matrix objects look like in C++ code:

```
template<int C, int R, typename T>
struct mat {
    PyObject ob_base;
    uint8_t info;
    glm::mat<C, R, T> super_type;
};
```

That is most likely why it's not quite compatible to glm matrices.

If you're using the latest version of PyGLM, `value_ptr(mat4)` should return a `LP_c_float` object, i.e. a `float*`.
I'm sure there is a way to transfer such a pointer over to boost::python, though as I said, I don't know how.

Technically you could convert the pointer to an integer, transfer that and cast it back to a `float*`.
You can get the address of a pointer by using:

```
int.from_bytes(ptr, "little")
```

Alternatively you could simply send over a bytes object.

```
as_bytes = bytes(mat4)
```

Or as a tuple:

```
as_tuple = mat4.to_tuple()
```

Or as a numpy array (which seems to have it's own boost::python::numpy module):

```
np_arr = numpy.array(mat4)
```

---

I was able to get the right output by passing the memory address as an `int*` back to C++ which then did some slicing to get it back into a `glm::mat4`, but I found this solution too convoluted and ended up wrapping the `glm::mat4` class manually (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62672081/9238288 for a basic example of how to achieve this).